# Next.JS 13 , How to redirect user from error page to home page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to redirect the user from the error page in the app folder back to the main page.
I am building a weather, so in case the user inputs a wrong city he should be able to go back to the Home Screen. I tried using router but it didn't work. Here is the error page

```js
"use client";
import Nav from "@/components/Nav";
import Wrapper from "@/components/Wrapper";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
const Error = ({ error, reset }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleGoBack = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("go back");
    router.push(`/?city=london`);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleGoBack}>
        <button>go back</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Error;
```

I also tried using `next()` but it just retry the fetch the wrong city.

Answer (score 0):

Next 13 has a few helpers that they export from `next/navigation`, including `redirect`. If you want to redirect on the server, then:

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
```

Then:

`redirect('/?city=london')`

however you need it in your page/action.

Comment: Sry but it didn't work

Comment: Do you have a minimal repro?

Answer (score 0):

Form is not needed, more information about the Link component can be found [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#props).

```js
import Link from 'next/link';

// you dont need form, Link is enough
<Link
 href={{
   pathname: '/',
   query: {
     city: 'London',
   },
 }}
>
 Back to home
</Link>;
```